# Iterate/parse multiple values in file

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I've been working to improve some results for a function I wrote to extract a list from a file, but have hit a wall. I've gotten as far as to pull a value and possibly two but fairly inconsistent. The results vary as far as the labels and values are concerned (examples below). I think regex may be the way to go, but I am a novice at best at using it.

Ex1:

```
Run                    Bora Hot   Record                                       Casing  Record
 No.                   From                 To            Sue                      fr                    To

One       4 .3/4    4569                    TD            5.5     15   .5      Surface               4569
```

Expected Result = Bit: 4 3/4, From: 4569, To: TD, Case: 5.5, Wt: 15.5

Ex2:

```
Run                    Bore- Hoke  Record                                        Casing Record
 No.       Bit          From                 To            Size      Wgt.           from
 Onel    4.75      4587                  4840            5 .5       N/ A         Surface
```

Expected Result = Bit: 4.75, From: 4587, To: 4840, Size: 5.5, Wt: N/A

Ex3:

```
Run                     Bore-Ho  Record                                        Ceng     Record
 No.                    From                  To            Sue       Wot             From 
One       4 .3/  4    4679                  TD             5 .1/  2   15 .5       Surface
```

Expected result: Bit: 4 3/4, From: 4679, To: TD, Case: 5 1/2, Wt: 15.5

Sample of code below. I'm not going to paste the library but you get a general idea of what I was doing. Again, I believe this is ineffective modus.

```
def far_m(lab,txt):
txt2 = txt.strip().split('       ')[-1]
pos = -1
if isMatch(lab,txt2):
    t1 = txt2.strip().split()[0]
    pos = txt.find(t1)

for i,r in enumerate(rtxt):
    if far_m('case', r) > -1:
        if i >= 2:
            rx = far_m('case', r)
            j = i-2
            rj = rtxt[j]
            if len(rj) > rx:
                # z = rj[int(rx/2):]
                a = rj
                a1 = get_start(rj,int(rx*0.7))
                a2 = get_start(rj,len(rj))
                ap = str(rj)[a1:a2]
                x1 = get_start(rj,a1+0.3*fn)
                x2 = get_start(rj,x1+0.42*fn)
                x3 = get_start(rj,x2+0.5*fn)
                x4 = get_start(rj,x3+0.5*fn)
                b1 = a[a1:x1].strip()
                b2 = a[x1:x2].strip()
                b3 = a[x2:x3].strip()
                b4 = a[x3:].strip()
                if b1 == '' and b2 != '' and b4 != '':
                    b1 = '7'
                found.foundList.append(['size', b1.strip()])
                found.foundList.append(['wt', b2.strip()])
                found.foundList.append(['to', b3.strip()])
                found.foundList.append(['from', b4.strip()])
```

Comment: Is your data really full of typos like that?  "Bora Hot" and "Bore- Hoke" and "Bore-Ho" instead of "Bore-Hole"?  "Sue" vs "Size"?  "Wot" vs "Wgt."?

Comment: @JohnZwinck  It is, it comes in inconsistent

Comment: Then I guess the first thing you need to do is simply clean your data to fix all the typos.  No need for regex: you can do it using some dictionaries where you map the bad names to the proper ones.